# Autofill feature isn't iterating numbers properly when using the AVERAGE() formula in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of monthly data which I want to use to create a new quarterly data column. In order to do this, I take increments of 3 months of data from the monthly data column and use the AVERAGE() formula on them. 
I have something like;

**AVERAGE(D13:D15) Y1(January - March)**

**AVERAGE(D16:D18) Y1(April - June)**

**AVERAGE(D19:D21) Y1(July - September)**

**AVERAGE(D22:D24) Y1(October - December)**

Since the data spans almost an entire century, I want to use the autofill feature to make my life a lot easier. To my dismay, Excel isn't recognizing my iteration of 3 cells at a time and instead giving me results something like this;

**AVERAGE(D13:D15) Y1(January - March)**

**AVERAGE(D16:D18) Y1(April - June)**

**AVERAGE(D19:D21) Y1(July - September)**

**AVERAGE(D22:D24) Y1(October - December)**

AVERAGE(D17:D19) Y1(May - July)

AVERAGE(D20:D22) Y1(August - October)

AVERAGE(D23:D25) Y1(November, December) - Y2(January)

AVERAGE(D26:D28) Y2(February - April)

Rather than:

**AVERAGE(D13:D15) Y1(January - March)**

**AVERAGE(D16:D18) Y1(April - June)**

**AVERAGE(D19:D21) Y1(July - September)**

**AVERAGE(D22:D24) Y1(October - December)**

AVERAGE(D25:D27) Y2(January - March)

AVERAGE(D28:D30) Y2(April - June)

AVERAGE(D31:D33) Y2(July - September)

AVERAGE(D34:D36) Y2(October - December)

Is there any workaround to this or am I going to have to manually convert all my monthly data to quarterly data?

Comment: Would you please expound a little on your formula? =AVERAGE(D13:D15), but what does Y1 refer to? Is this just a text, another column? I'm confused. Perhaps a screenshot to show explicitly what you are doing and then I can help.

Comment: By Y1 I just mean Year 1. I put it there to help better explain my situation, it is not actually anything I input into excel. For example Y1(January-March) signifies the average of the three months January, February, and March, which correspond to cells D13, D14, and D15 respectively.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I would have to ask you again to defer to my initial question, or statement. I need to see what these cells look like via image or a data paste in order to assess what you are doing with your expectations.

Comment: Here is an example of a question that has detail. I was looking at this question today: EX) http://superuser.com/questions/1141300/ms-excel-formula-for-fitting-things-in-buckets

Comment: Or like this. This question includes snapshots: http://superuser.com/questions/1140291/treat-row-labels-as-number-instead-of-text-in-excel-pivot-chart

Comment: It seems perfectly clear what he's asking, the outcome of the formulae isn't really relevant, as he just wants the formula to repeat down, incrementing in rows of 3.  Autofill, but for 3 rows not 1.  Screenshots not really relevant

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your first quarterly cell
(the one that contains `=AVERAGE(D13:D15)`) is `Q42`. 
Replace that formula with `=AVERAGE(OFFSET($D$13, 3*(ROW()-42), 0, 3, 1))`,
and drag/fill that down. 
The `OFFSET` function lets you access cells
without needing to enter their addresses literally (e.g., `D25`);
you can say, in effect, the 12th cell down from cell `D13`. 
This formula says,

- Take the current row number (`ROW()`) and subtract 42
  (the row number of cell `Q42`, where you want the Y1 Q1 average). 
  Obviously, this evaluates to 0 in cell `Q42`. 
  When this is dragged down to cell `Q43`, it evaluates to 1, etc. 
  In `Q46` (where you want the Y2 Q1 average), you get 4.
- Multiply by 3. 
  Obviously, this gives you the number of months since the beginning (January Y1).
- Starting at `D13`, go down the number of months just computed,
  and go zero columns to the right. 
  Then take the `AVERAGE` of the range
  that is three rows high and one column wide.

Answer (score 0):

Autofill will only ever increment references 1 row per row dragged.  To get a different interval, use the `=row()` function with a multiplier.

`=ROW(A1)*3+10` evaluates to row number of A1 * 3, plus 10, i.e 13 incrementing by 3 each row

`INDIRECT` takes a text string and turns it into a reference, so

`=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("D"&ROW(A1)*3+10&":D"&ROW(A1)*3+12))`

evaluates to

`average(indirect("D"&13&":D"&15)`

which further goes to

`=AVERAGE(D13:D15)`

And this will drag down as follows

```
=AVERAGE(D13:D15)
=AVERAGE(D16:D18)
=AVERAGE(D19:D21)
=AVERAGE(D22:D24)
=AVERAGE(D25:D27)
=AVERAGE(D28:D30)
=AVERAGE(D31:D33)
=AVERAGE(D34:D36)
=AVERAGE(D37:D39)
=AVERAGE(D40:D42)
=AVERAGE(D43:D45)
=AVERAGE(D46:D48)
=AVERAGE(D49:D51)
```

etc.

---

As a bonus, the following formula will drag down your labels, although this could be done with some clever autofilling of 2 cells (1 containing the year part and one containing the months part) joined together with an `&`)

`="Y"&ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/4,0)&" "&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MOD(ROW(A1),4),1,"(January - March)"),2,"(April - June)"),3,"(July - September)"),0,"(October - December)")`

will drag down as:

```
Y1 (January - March)
Y1 (April - June)
Y1 (July - September)
Y1 (October - December)
Y2 (January - March)
Y2 (April - June)
Y2 (July - September)
Y2 (October - December)
Y3 (January - March)
Y3 (April - June)
Y3 (July - September)
Y3 (October - December)
Y4 (January - March)
Y4 (April - June)
Y4 (July - September)
Y4 (October - December)
Y5 (January - March)
```

etc.